# Shift One Cell down in Column in R conditionally

Tags: r

I will reproduce

```
v1 <- c(40,45,46,45,46,43,45)
v2 <- c(41,19,44,45,23,44,42)
df <- data.frame(v1,v2)

v1 v2
40 41 
45 19
46 44
45 45
46 23
43 44
45 42
```

My desired result is

```
if v1 - v2 > 10
```

Then I should have the cells in this order.

```
v1 v2
40 41
45 NA
46 19
45 44
46 45
43 NA
45 23
NA 44
NA 42
```

Is it too complex?

Comment: Because you are writing these as columns, I think you mean these variables to be in a data.frame.  But then, the columns must have the same length.  Do you mean for v1 to have an NA at the end as well?

Comment: Yes, it would be a data.frame, I just edited it. Thanks. Also, add NA at the end of V1, no problemo

Comment: Do you mean for `df$v1[5]` to be NA?

Comment: just to have the same length DF, yes, let's do df$v1[5] as NA.

Comment: Does this need to be repeated? Notice that in your proposed answer df$v1[3] - df$v2[3] > 10  (after the first shift).

Comment: yes there would be. I just re-edited

Answer (score 0):

I believe there would a better approach to this but it's good for starters :)

```
v1 <- c(40,45,46,45,46,43,45)
v2 <- c(41,19,44,45,23,44,42)
df <- data.frame(v1,v2)

update_df <- function(df){
  v1 <- df$v1
  v2 <- df$v2
  v1 <- c(v1,NA)
  v2 <- c(v2[1:i-1],NA,v2[i:length(v2)])
  return(cbind.data.frame(v1,v2))
}

k <- nrow(df)
skip <- FALSE

for(i in 1:k)
{
  if(df$v1[i] - df$v2[i] > 10 & skip == F)
    { df <- update_df(df)
      k <- nrow(df)
      skip <- TRUE
      next}
  skip <- FALSE
}
```